# Modifying pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql, shell, ubuntu

I want to modify the line

```
local all all peer
```

to

```
local all all md5
```

within a shell script. What is the best way to go about this? If I am to search for the line, what string should I be looking for? There are a lot of spaces between each word in the pg_hba.conf

Or is there a better way at doing this?

Thank you

Comment: a combination of SED and AWK would be good for this. https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -i  '/^local all all peer/ s/peer/md5/' pg_hba.conf
```